# Visual Studio post-build: keep console open?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, console, post-build-event

My post-build event works, but in some situations I am quite sure it is showing an error in the console window. However, because the window closes immediately, I'm not able to read any of it.

This is the build event:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release start xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)../../bin"
```

Basically it copies the built dlls over to another directory.

Is there a way to force the console window invoked by `start` to remain open until I close it?

Comment: Append `&& pause` to the command.

Comment: That does not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the information that you want is written in the "Output" (Views > Output or Ctrl-W + O). That information is still written/available after everything has ran.

For example, the output for

```
echo Information on the post build event
some_non_existant_command
```

is

```
Information on the post build event
'some_non_existant_command' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

which will give you a better hint at what's going wrong than the Error List (Ctrl-W + E) which will only display something cryptical, like *"... exited with code 9009"*.

So, my advice, check the Output!

Hope it helps.